# Uno Platform: Reading JSON configuration file in Android project

Tags: xamarin, uno-platform

I'm trying to integrate `IConfiguration` with the Uno Platform this way:

```
public class Startup
{
    internal static void Init()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains("appsettings.json"));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
        {
            using (var s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                //var content = s.ReadToEnd();

                var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.AddJsonStream(s);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((c, x) => ConfigureServices(c, x))
                .ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole(abc =>
                {
                    abc.DisableColors = true;
                }))
                .Build();
            }
        }
    }
```

I defined `appsettings.json` in my Shared project as Embedded Resource and copy always.

When running with UWP it runs successfully, but with Android it fails with the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The path must be absolute. Parameter name: root'

In my (other) Xamarin project, it works as expected with this addition:

```
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.AddCommandLine(new string[] { $"ContentRoot={Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory}" });
                    c.AddJsonStream(stream);
                })
```

but Xamarin Essentials is out of the scope of the Uno Platform as I understand...

Comment: Most of the Xamarin Essentials APIs are compatible with Uno Platform, at least for Android/iOS/UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with the following

```
    var resourcePrefix = "";

#if __IOS__
            resourcePrefix = "UnoApp.iOS.";
#endif
#if __ANDROID__
            resourcePrefix = "UnoApp.Droid.";
#endif
#if WINDOWS_UWP
            resourcePrefix = "UnoApp.";
#endif

            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(Startup)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
                (resourcePrefix + "appsettings.json");

            var conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonStream(stream);

            Configuration = conf.Build();

            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConfiguration), Configuration);
```

Comment: If you have solved this issue by yourself, please mark your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.